# HttpResponeMessage returns 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: c#, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponsemessage

I'm trying to connect to an api, but I get the following result :

```
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Vary: Origin
  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.url
  Date: Sat, 30 Jan 2021 22:56:45 GMT
  Set-Cookie: TS0182ab0d=0180bb6f22515cbe2cddec42f2bdc8cb4b394bf2447928c095c41f950fab6ce3b59180574be0cf84ba91749969bb6cfafcaf801f7d; Path=/; Domain=.api2.mofidonline.com
  Content-Length: 0
}
```

and this is my headers

```
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("authority", "api2.example.url");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
string str = "BasicAuthentication" + mCookie["api-token"];
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("authorization", str);
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "*/*");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("origin", "https://example.url");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("sec-fetch-site", "same-site");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("sec-fetch-mode", "cors");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("sec-fetch-dest", "empty");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("referer", "https://example.url/Home/Default/page-1");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
```

Comment: it's **Basic** instead **BasicAuthentication** no?

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct:

```
string str = "BasicAuthentication" + mCookie["api-token"];
```

It's "Basic" and then you need a space followed by the username and password joined by a colon, as a Base64 encoded string for the credentials.

For example:

```
string base64EncodedCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password"));
string authorizationHeader = "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials;
```